# How to show four windows (full screen mode, OpenGL render) each on different monitor at the same time?

Tags: opengl, glfw

1. Create window1 and render texture that I want to share to window2, window3, window4
2. All the windows are in full screen mode.
3. Display at different monitor, like the schematic below.
4. Need Synchronize (one thread, four opengl contexts, four FBOs, one render texture)

   Monitor1    Monitor2    Monitor3   Monitor4
   --------------   ------------   -----------   -----------
   | window1 | | window2 |  | window3 |  | window4 |
   --------------   ------------   -----------   -----------

I tried to use glfw example [sharing.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/examples/sharing.c) and create window1 like this

```
int count;
GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count);
printf("Monitor count: %d\n", count);           

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
window1 = glfwCreateWindow( g_dispWidth, g_dispHeight, "circle mask", monitors[0], NULL);
```

This will show the full screen window on monitor[0], but when I use two windows I only can show one window (window1) on monitor1. If I choose to show the other window (window2) on monitor2, the window1 will hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to have a single window spanning the 4 monitors.

You could then use 4 viewports in a single context to render the images on the different monitors.

This should be efficient unless you have multiple graphics adapters.

That would look like (untested) :

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, 0);
GLFWwindow* w = glfwCreateWindow(3840, 2160, "window1", NULL, NULL);
glfwSetWindowPos(w, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I turn to use SDL. 
```m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("window1", 0, 0, 3840, 2160, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL |SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS );```This will work like I expected. But I still don't know how to do when using glfw .

Comment: @JuliaDing I've added an untested example, best would that you refer to glfw comprehensive documentation : https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html

Comment: It still only render on one monitor

Comment: I use xrandr like [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214841) it works.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further as I'm on vacation right now, perhaps if you update your question with you latest code, and Mark it as unanswered, someone can take it from here ?